# Hibernate OnDemand eager-fetch

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading

I understand how to configure my model to fetch eager or lazy.
But how should i tell my application to eager-fetch a collection just this time?

In other words. I have a DAO with a get-method. `EntityDao.getEntity(entityId)`
This entity has a collection of `Children` which is lazy-loaded by default.

Lets say the dao-method is transactional.

Most of the time i only need the Entity without the children, but every once in a while i need to eager fetch the children. Now how would i go about that?

If i understand this all correct, then the session only lives within the transaction. So after the transaction ends (in this case after the dao-method) then no more lazy-fetching can be done.
So then i can either put my transaction further up my code, or eager fetch my object within the transaction?

So how would i do this eager-fetch within my transaction?

What are my options?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You shouldn't do the transaction in the dao. The transaction should span the whole business operation, that's the sense of having transactions.

You also destroy lazy loading. It should be transparent to the caller, which is the case when the session is still available and the children are loaded when accessing them. After closing the session, lazy loading isn't possible anymore and entities should be accessed.

Comment: Well hello and thanks for your reply. But i said "Lets SAY i got the transaction in the dao". I do not have it there.

Comment: Ok, then you shouldn't have a problem with lazy loading. Just don't use entities when there is no session.

Comment: Aha. Now i see what you are suggesting. Well the thing is, my buisness logic is in a axis1.3 webservice and transactions does not work there... So im looking for a simple way to get me a preinstantiated object in the webservice

Comment: I don't know what environment you are working in. In our case it was easiest to have lazy loading only in the server where we have access to the database. All clients only receive DTOs. We stopped trying to serialize entities, because we had too many issues.

Answer (score 1):

You should use fetch profile feature of hibernate refer [doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-profiles) for more detail and [example](http://blog.frankel.ch/hibernate-hard-facts-part-6)